# can't get data from database to dropdownlist in loginview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

I have this code on an aspx page.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSize" CssClass="textbox" Width="100px">
<asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" />
<asp:ListItem Value="11" Text="11. Mands" />
<asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="7. Mands" />
<asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Ikke Kamp"/>
</asp:DropDownList>


 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlType" CssClass="textbox" Width="100px">
 <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" />
 <asp:ListItem Value="K" Text="Kamp" />
 <asp:ListItem Value="T" Text="Træning" />
 <asp:ListItem Value="E" Text="Aktivitet"/>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

ts inside a loginview with some other fields (textbox)
Im trying to get a record id into the page so i can edit it, I have fix it with the Textbox and its working 100%, but i cant get the value from the database into the dropdownlist so it show that value as selected.
I have tryed these 3 codes, but nothing is working fore the dropdownlist.

```
// DataValueField               
Dim drop_obj As DropDownList = TryCast(LoginView2.FindControl("ddlSize"), DropDownList)
drop_obj.DataValueField = dtEvents.Rows(0)("EventEventSize")

Dim drop_obj2 As DropDownList = TryCast(LoginView2.FindControl("ddlType"), DropDownList)
drop_obj2.DataValueField = dtEvents.Rows(0)("EventType")

// SelectedIndex
Dim drop_obj As DropDownList = TryCast(LoginView2.FindControl("ddlSize"), DropDownList)
drop_obj.SelectedIndex = dtEvents.Rows(0)("EventEventSize")

Dim drop_obj2 As DropDownList = TryCast(LoginView2.FindControl("ddlType"), DropDownList)
drop_obj2.SelectedIndex = dtEvents.Rows(0)("EventType")

// SelectedValue
Dim drop_obj As DropDownList = TryCast(LoginView2.FindControl("ddlSize"), DropDownList)
drop_obj.SelectedValue = dtEvents.Rows(0)("EventEventSize")

Dim drop_obj2 As DropDownList = TryCast(LoginView2.FindControl("ddlType"), DropDownList)
drop_obj2.SelectedValue = dtEvents.Rows(0)("EventType")
```

Can someone plz. help !? I have values in the 2 dtEvents.Rows(0) i have checked that, with a debug and then step-into.
and i get values like 7 or 11 and T or K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to datebind your table to your list.

You want to utilize these two properties:

```
DataTextField
DataValueField
```

So, you want to set your `DataTextField` (what the user will see) to the column taht contains the display text and then you want to set your `DataValueField` (the value of the item that won't be seen) to the column containing that. Then you want to call `DataBind()`.

For example (my VB is very rusty):

```
Dim myDDL AS DropDownList();

myDDL.DataTextField = myTable("ColumnDataUserSees")
myDDL.DataValueField = myTable("ColumnDataIWillUse")
myDDL.DataBind()
```

Definitely check that syntax. I've been using C# for months and no VB, so that's probably not 100%.